# Modern trimless windows

Tags: drywall, windows, trim

Is it possible to not use casing on interior casement windows? The drywall is already in and its too late to change the framing. There is a gap between the window and the drywall that the casing would cover.

[image]

Comment: It is possible not to use casing/trim, but it requires more exact work so there are no gaps and usually both the drywall/window is installed together.

Comment: Yup, basically you have to do fussy drywall work without the gap. Lacking pictures, likely easiest to just replace that piece of drywall with a bigger one than to splice in a little strip to fill the gap. If you [edit] your question to include some pictures better suggestions might result.

Comment: Using trim probably saves two or three hours per window and need a master drywaller to make it look nice.

Comment: What you save in trim carpentry labor/time, you may spend in drywall labor/time, so it may well end up as a wash in the end. And, of course, it's possible. What's your _actual_ question?

Answer (score 1):

If, for purposes of "modern" and basically "fashion" or "style" you want no trim, you can have no trim. It may cost *more* than trim, but if that's *not the point* and the look is, then no need to belabor that.

You will probably need to remove the drywall that's "done" in the area of the window and re-do it, or have it re-done, to a higher standard in order to avoid the gaps that trim would cover for the perfectly average drywall job you have there now. Fortunately, the material cost of drywall is low. The labor cost of getting it precise is where the cost lives.